# How to hide Laravel crsf token from appearing in URL?

Tags: laravel

I have a GET form with a crsf token.

```
<form action="{{ url('search') }}" method="get">
  @csrf             
  <input type="text" name="q">
</form>
```

The problem is that even if `@csrf` creates a hidden field, when submitting the form, the token appears in the URL. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: dont use the GET method (it passes the inputs through the query string), the CSRF token isn't even checked for GET requests

Comment: So basically it's useless to use @crsf for GET forms, because the user can pass info via the URL anyways. Is this correct ?

Comment: because they are GET requests (reading) ... wouldn't it be weird to have to pass a token to your site to reach the homepage or any page? if that was the case no one would be able to reach any page as they would never be able to get the token in the first place ... hyperlinks (which cause GET requests) would be useless

Comment: but there is no difference between you submitting that form to that URL and it adding the query string or you typing that url yourself and adding query string parameters or a link doing that ... i hope that all make sense `:)`

Comment: Yep, it's clear. Thanks! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the @csrf and it will work for you.